# How to Migrate Memberships

Tags: wordpress, civimember

Our organization currently has several membership levels and has since 2014. We are moving to a single membership level and sustaining contributions instead. Is there a way, short of an Update SQL Script to move anybody with Membership A to Membership B?

Answer (score 1):

A 'way' would be to export all Membership data together with Internal ID, then manipulate the data as you want, and then delete all existing member data and then doing an Import. It may feel 'safer' than in mysql since you will be able to make whatever tweaks might be required for those 'odd case' members.

Comment: You'll lose user activity that way won't you?

Comment: Which user Activity are you thinking of? Membership Renewal Activities etc? Not certain. Best to test.

Comment: The entire activity log

Comment: sorry i don't follow. why would deleting membership records (not the Contacts) affect Activities - unless you mean just membership related Activities? is this a terminology question. in Civi a contact is a contact. and a contact can have membership records.

Comment: Oh yes I guess I misunderstood, but I supposed anything membership related might stick around.